# Getting long 'dirty' strings from SQL Server database into a 'clean' excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, excel, replace

I Have a table in which comments are kept about clients. This is an open field and be very long and include line breaks.

When I try and export this to Excel, the data is misaligned. I'd like to return as much of the comment as possible in an excel cell, without anything like a line break.

Is there a way I could do this in Excel? (Find and replace)
Is there a way to structure my SQL query to only return what I can fit?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Perhaps Excel is not the right tool to browse comments about clients?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to deal with this is to enclose all suspect String columns with Speech marks ""  and then in excel under the text to columns option make sure to select speech marks as a text qualifier.

This always worked for me.

Just be sure to remove speech marks from the string column in question otherwise it will split it again.

Another method i used was to used an obscure delimiter like an Ibar | which was not likely to be found in my data and by again using the Text to columns option i specified the IBar as the column separator which did just what i needed.

T